# arrays.xml:16: error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

Tags: xml, android-layout

```
<string-array name="screen_orientation_entryvalues"><item>sensor</item><item>landscape</item>unspecified</item></string-array>
<string-array name="solar_emulation_entries"><item>L + left/right</item><item>"Device's light sensor"</item></string-array>
<string-array name="solar_emulation_entryvalues"><item>user_setting</item><item>light_sensor</item></string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

The last `item` in the first `string-array` has an unmatched end tag.

Here it is with the matching start tag added:

```
<resources>
  <string-array name="screen_orientation_entryvalues"><item>sensor</item><item>landscape</item><item>unspecified</item></string-array>
  <string-array name="solar_emulation_entries"><item>L + left/right</item><item>"Device's light sensor"</item></string-array>
  <string-array name="solar_emulation_entryvalues"><item>user_setting</item><item>light_sensor</item></string-array>
</resources>
```